# DropDownList selected item always first item in list

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a DropDownList in a user control; however, no matter what I do I can't get any of the "selected" properties (SelectedItem, SelectedIndex, SelectedValue) to populate correctly. The value of all three of these properties is the first item in my list no matter which item was actually selected.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ParticipantsSelectList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Please select a team...</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="{D37EFA0C-988A-4A2A-8D6E-80E3BAE00DEE}">Blue Team</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="{7543E282-C9B8-435A-86A2-70E8E3BB38E5}">Green Team</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="{F6BEF34A-215E-4179-9F4C-68F7C43D755F}">Orange Team</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="{D50AD44A-686A-4BD3-B62E-D70ABF153AE5}">Red Team</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="{DEFB7DA6-B0FF-4C36-A015-F3E8BC7AECA2}">Yellow Team</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="{D37EFA0C-988A-4A2A-8D6E-80E3BAE00DEE},{7543E282-C9B8-435A-86A2-70E8E3BB38E5},{F6BEF34A-215E-4179-9F4C-68F7C43D755F},{D50AD44A-686A-4BD3-B62E-D70ABF153AE5},{DEFB7DA6-B0FF-4C36-A015-F3E8BC7AECA2}">All Teams</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

---

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ParticipantsSelectList.SelectedValue)) // SelectedValue is always empty string (value of the first item in the list)
    {
        resultsPanel.Visible = true;
        selectTeamLabel.Visible = false;
        GenerateResultsTable();
    }
    else
    {
        resultsPanel.Visible = false;
        selectTeamLabel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting the selected value when page loads so its always the first item value of the list....

Answer (score 3):

Try using `!Page.IsPostBack` in `Page_Load`

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    { 
        //Your Code....
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really make sense. If I'm checking the value of a drop down list how can I do this inside of !Page.IsPostBack

Comment: Oh sorry.. I was blind... Are you trying to get the selected value after a button click or only when the page loads.... ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think we're getting somewhere here. I originally was checking in Page_Load because I was trying to do an AutoPostback on the DropDownList. However, when I added the submit button I left the logic in Page_Load. But if I add an onClick function on the submit button and check the value there it works. So if I want to do an AutoPostback where should I check the selected value?

Comment: It seems like I can accomplish this with the SelectedIndexChanged event. Thanks for your help.